# I currently have an array of objects which each have props for each item in the portfolio: a name, an id, and image that will be displayed

Tags: reactjs

I’m currently making a portfolio in React and I have a question.

I currently have an array of objects which each have props for each item in the portfolio: a name,position, id and an image that will be displayed. 
I have cards with some information displayed(name and positons), but i couldn't manage to connect images with every id like I did with names and positions.

```
<img alt='players' src={} />
```

Thank you for your help and time.

```
export const players = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name1',
    position: 'striker',
    photo: `./pictures/player1.jpg`
},
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2',
    position: 'center midfield'
    photo: `./pictures/player2.jpg`
  },
...


//Card

import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {
      return(
         <div className='tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-1'>
           <img alt='players' src={props.photo} />
           <div> 
            <h2>{props.name}</h2> 
            <p>{props.position}</p>             
          </div>
         </div>
        );
}

export default Card;



//Card List 

import React from 'react';
import  Card from './Card';


const CardList = ({ players }) => {
   return (
    <div>
    {
      players.map((user,i) => {
       return (
        <Card 
         key={i} 
         id={players[i].id} 
         name={players[i].name} 
         position={players[i].position}
         photo={players[i].photo}
         />
         );
       })
      }
    </div> 
   );
}

export default CardList;
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: i cant manage to add the photos from players to <img alt='players' src={} /> in //Card

Comment: open chrome dev tools, inspect your broken images, and it will show you the src - make sure the path is correct. try it without the `.` e.g. `/pictures/player2.jpg`

Comment: <img alt="players">   in inspect element, no src , any idea why?

Comment: you are using single quotes `'` for the other strings such as name and position, but something else for photo. try using single/double quotes instead of `\`` although backticks `\`` should work.

Comment: still no src in img , i appreciate the help man, i cant figure it out if the prblm is in getting the photos in the players,js or passing on in the Card.js

Comment: I found the problem, there is a missing `,` in `players` after 'center midfield' :)